# How to use a breakpoint after await in unit test?

Tags: c#, nunit, async-await, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I am surprised my breakpoint after `await`ing an `async` method that is on a line that references the awaited `Task<T>` is never hit:

```
    [Test]
    public async void GetSomethingTest()
    {
        var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>();
        var result = await service.TryGetSomethingAsync(20);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccess);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.ReturnValue);
    }
```

Putting a breakpoint on the first `Assert` line is never hit but the test passes.

How to I break when await returns?

*UPDATE*: I guess it is because the test framework is not `await`ing the invocation of the test method, I am using NUnit 2.6.3 and that claims `async` support, however whether that entails breaking after an `await` like I am trying to do, I am not sure...

Comment: Change your test method from async void to async Task

Comment: @Neel that didn't help :(

Comment: I've had all kind of problems with debugging unit tests. If it does not work the way your wanted, copy your test to a ConsoleApplication and debug them there. That's a lot less trouble.

Comment: I grow more frustrated with Visual Studio and/or NUnit every day.  I cannot properly set breakpoints within async-based tests.  I followed all suggested answers here and nothing works. Currently on NUnit 3.13.1

May just go back to Java, NodeJS & Python. II never have these unexpected, unacceptable silly issues with any of those.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that your method is `async void`. That has fire-and-forget semantics.

Conceptually what your method is doing with the `async`-`await` usage looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetSomethingTest()
{
    var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>();
    service.TryGetSomethingAsync(20).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var result = t.Result;
        Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccess);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.ReturnValue);
    });
}
```

Now it should be clear what the problem is. Your test method immediately returns as soon as `TryGetSomethingAsync` returns its `Task`. So the test immediately finishes. Since no exceptions were thrown, it is a success.

**If your test framework supports `Task`-returning tests,** you can fix your test to do what you want by simply changing its return type to `Task` instead of `void`.

```
[Test]
public async Task GetSomethingTest()
{
    var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>();
    var result = await service.TryGetSomethingAsync(20);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccess);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result.ReturnValue);
}
```

This will conceptually translate to the following.

```
[Test]
public Task GetSomethingTest()
{
    var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>();
    return service.TryGetSomethingAsync(20).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var result = t.Result;
        Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccess);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.ReturnValue);
    });
}
```

Notice how the `Task` continuation is returned, so that the test framework can now wait on it, ensuring that all the test's code has time to run before the test is considered finished.

(Technically a framework could be made to work in the `async void` case as well, but I don't know of any reason why that would be a good feature, so I expect most don't handle it.)

**If your test framework does not support Task-returning tests,** you can fix your test by using `.Result` instead of `await`.

```
[Test]
public void GetSomethingTest()
{
    var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>();
    var result = service.TryGetSomethingAsync(20).Result;
    Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccess);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result.ReturnValue);
}
```

This will simply block the current thread until the `Task` returned by `TryGetSomethingAsync` is completed.

Comment: Switching to MSTest and returning `Task` solved my problem, but thanks the detailed answer, I am sure it will help other!